# Loading multiple datasets without overwriting variable

Tags: matlab, variables, file-io

I have a folder containing a number of files, named:

```
filename_1.mat
filename_2.mat
.
.
.
filename_n.mat
```

Each file contains a dataset named `Var`, with identical columns. I want to load all these datasets into the workspace and use `vertcat()` to vertically concatenate them, but when I load them in a for loop I only get the last dataset since the variable `Var` is overwritten. These datasets were created in a for loop:

```
% generate filenames

tss = arrayfun(@(x){sprintf('filename_%d',x)},1:(length(1:3)))';
namerr = cell((length(1:3)),1);
namerr(:,1) = {'E:\FILES\'};
file_names = strcat(namerr,tss,'.mat');

% create datasets and save them to E:\FILES 

for ii = 1:3
    a = rand(1,5)';
    b = rand(1,5)';
    Var = dataset({[a,b],'a_name','b_name'});
    save(file_names{(ii)},'Var','-v6')
end

% Now read these datasets into workspace and concatenate vertically??
% Is there a way for me to name the datasets `Var_1...Var_n`
% so they are not overwritten?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  You can load the data into a variable, and then access the contents of a file as fields in the variable.  Starting with your example, this would look something like this:

```
loadedData_1 = load(file_names{1})
loadedData_2 = load(file_names{2})
loadedData_3 = load(file_names{3})

mergedData = [...
    loadedData_1.Var; ...
    loadedData_2.Var; ...        
    loadedData_3.Var   ];
```

You can clean this up by using a loop:

```
for ix = 3:-1:1   %Load all data, backwards to force preallocation
    loadedData(ix) = load(file_names{ix});
end
mergedData = cat(1,loadedData.Var);
```

Or if you really want to go over the top I think you can do it in one long line using `arrayfun`, but that's probably going over the top.

Answer (score 1):

It would be far easier to just do it directly in the loop:

```
...
Varcat = [];
for ii = 1:3
    a = rand(1,5)';
    b = rand(1,5)';
    Var = dataset({[a,b],'a_name','b_name'});
    Varcat = [Varcat; Var];
    save(file_names{(ii)},'Var','-v6')
end

Var = Varcat;
```

In case you actually want to do it much later or in another part of the program, hopefully it's clear how to adapt the same approach for a similar loop with `load()`.